# jQuery to update checkbox value, depending on radio field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Goal is to update checkbox fields to equal TRUE or FALSE, depending which radio button option is picked. If I select FALSE, then the checkboxes must be unchecked.

I'm only able to get the checkboxes ticked if I select TRUE. Is it because I defined that as a value?

```
     $(function() {
var MAIN= $("input[type='radio'][value='TRUE']");
var marketing1 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='']");
var marketing2 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='']");

    MAIN.on('change', function()
        {
      if ($(this).val() == "TRUE")  {
             marketing1.prop('checked',this.checked);
             marketing2.prop('checked',this.checked);
        } if ($(this).val() == "FALSE") {
             marketing1.prop('checked',this.checked, false);
             marketing2.prop('checked',this.checked, false);
        }

    });
});
```

From HTML

```
     <input type="radio" name="MAIN" value="TRUE"/> Yes
     <input type="radio" name="MAIN" value="FALSE"/> No

First -  <input type="checkbox" name="marketing1" value=""/>
Second -  <input type="checkbox" name="marketing2" value=""/>
```

Comment: Try using true and false like this:  "marketing1.prop('checked', true);"

Comment: Hi Rasmus, thanks for the input. Unfortunately the false version of that concept did not clear the value in the checkbox fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `this` and `checked`. I've adjusted your code:

```js
$(function() {
  var MAIN= $("input[type='radio']");
  var marketing1 = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='marketing1']");
  var marketing2 = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='marketing2']");

    MAIN.on('change', function()
        {
        if ($(this).val() == "TRUE")  {
          marketing1.prop('checked',true);
          marketing2.prop('checked',true);
        } else {
          marketing1.prop('checked',false);
          marketing2.prop('checked',false);
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="radio" name="MAIN" value="TRUE"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="MAIN" value="FALSE"/> No
<br>
First -  <input type="checkbox" name="marketing1" value=""/>
Second -  <input type="checkbox" name="marketing2" value=""/>
```

Comment: @Atheri No problem happy to help.